# Интеграционные тесты Django + Elasticsearch

Tags: django, тестирование, elasticsearch

Возникла необходимость протестировать клиентскую часть сайта. Работает на Django, поиск и выдача списков результатов - Elasticsearch. Так как данные в БД и Elasticsearch могут отличаться, нужно протестировать их совместное взаимодействие. Но если с тестированием Django проблем нет, так как создается тестовая база, то с Elasticsearch возникли проблемы - при формировании тестовой базы и создания интексов, они создаются в основной базе.

Вопрос: Как настроить Django + Elasticsearch , чтобы при тестировании не затрагивалась основная база?

Comment: Создать второй индекс в эластике

Comment: Можно пример ?.

Comment: Если у вас отдельно крутятся Джанго с тестовым сервером и Джанго с продом, то для тестовой задайте другой индекс в настройках.